# Prove $(1-\cos x)/\sin x = \tan x/2$

Tags: trigonometry

Using double angle and compound angles formulae prove,

$$
\frac{1-\cos x}{\sin x}     = \tan\frac{x}{2}
$$

Can someone please help me figure this question, I have no idea how to approach it?

Comment: Write it as $(1 - \cos(2y))/\sin(2y) = \tan y$. Do you see then how to proceed?

Comment: I'll try proceeding, thanks for the tip!

Comment: Im revising for a test, and im stuck on this question, and I still don't understand many of the hints/solutions people have given me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\dfrac{1-\cos x}{\sin x}=\dfrac{1-(1-2\sin^2\frac x2)}{2\sin\frac x 2\cos\frac x2}=\dfrac{\sin\frac x2}{\cos\frac x2}=\tan\frac x2$$

Comment: When a problem is marked "homework" please don't answer the problem completely.

Comment: THANKS! makes self teaching way easier

Answer (score 15):

Use geometry: $AO= 1$
It is strange that no one has mentioned this drawing yet.
[image: Weierstrass substitution]

P.S. Note that you can easily extract other trigonometric identites involving $\phi/2, 2\phi $  argument from this picture. For example to get $sin(\phi/2)$ use $ECD$ triangle and Pythagorean theorem to calculate $CD/ED = sin (\phi/2)$

Comment: I think, this is what  Red Queen10101 want

Comment: we haven't been taught this at school.

Comment: School in which pupils did not draw circles and triangles...O tempora, o mores!

Comment: Beautiful, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 6):

Hint: It is easier to show:

$$\frac{1-\cos 2y}{\sin 2y} = \tan y$$

using the formulas for $\cos 2y$ and $\sin 2y$.

Comment: hi ive used the formulas for cos2y and sin2y. Im still not catching the drift of continuing on.

Comment: What did you get?

Comment: (1- cos^2 x +sin^2 x)/ (2sinxcosx)

Comment: sorry the x represents y

Comment: $\cos^2 2x = 1-\sin^2 2x$

Comment: ziang chen, is it possible to post your solution, back up? I think I have of understanding your method.

Comment: @RedQueen10101 Now what is $1-\cos^2 x$?

Comment: hey Thomas, could you give me further of your solution, the 1-cos^2 x is what I got when I expanded it. Could you please show me how you did the question im desperate to know since I have a test on this topic.

Comment: Yes, but $1-\cos^2 x$ is equal to something else that you know. @RedQueen10101

Comment: Given that $\cos^2 x + \sin^2 x = 1$, what is $1-\cos^2 x$?

Answer (score 4):

$$
\cos x = \cos^2\frac{x}{2}-\sin^2\frac{x}{2} = 1-2\sin^2\frac{x}{2}
$$
and
$$
\sin x = 2\sin\frac{x}{2}\cos\frac{x}{2}
$$
so
$$
\frac{1-\cos x}{\sin x} = \frac{2\sin^2\frac{x}{2}}{2\sin\frac{x}{2}\cos\frac{x}{2}} = \frac{\sin\frac{x}{2}}{\cos\frac{x}{2}} = \tan\frac{x}{2}
$$

Comment: (provided $x\neq 0\mod \pi$, of course)

Comment: When a problemis marked "homework" please don't answer the problem completely.

Comment: Oh. My apologies.

Comment: Hi, im sorry to bug. Im still not understanding what you did on the first row with cosx=.....

Comment: You have $$\cos(u+v) = \cos u \cos v - \sin u\sin v$$ plug into this $u=v=\frac{x}{2}$.